# Flex: Fails to compile .as files

Tags: linux, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I've installed Flex SDK 4.6 in ubuntu through [this guide](http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/02/install-adobe-flex-ubuntu/).

There is a `~/helloworld.as` .

I'm trying to compile that by :

```
$ mxmlc ~/helloWorld.as
```

But fails to compile and get :

```
mxmlc: command not found
```

Please tell me what am i missing here ?

Comment: Obviously `mxmlc` is not on your classpath. That said, Adobe Flex' Linux support has been close to none. You'd probably be better to install the latest Apache Flex (v4.10), which is supposed to be fully Linux compatible and has a proper installer: http://flex.apache.org/installer.html

Comment: @RIAstar I thought the proper installer didn't support Linux yet--but don't quote me on that.

Comment: @Reboog711 I think I read something about the Linux version downloading the Mac .dmg file instead of the tarball, but I'd think that would be fixed by now.

Comment: @RIAstar They just posted download numbers to the Apache Flex list; and they said their were 6 Linux installs; so my understanding must have been wrong.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following command before using mxmlc.

```
$ sudo chmod +x /opt/flex/bin/mxmlc
```